# how to make npm package available for all users

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

I installed angular-cli on my root user. So when I check `ng version` it works and gives the angular version.

But when I check this from a non root user I cannot see it. How can I make this available for all users.

os - oracle linux 7

tried `npm config prefix /usr/local` it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the '`Network Service`' account use the folder:

```
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm
```